# Merging two numpy matrices to create element-wise tuple

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I'm not sure if this has been asked before but I couldn't find the solution to this seemingly simple problem. I have two arrays like so:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
y = np.array([[1,2,3],[7,8,9]])
```

And I want to create a merged matrix like:

```
merged = [[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)],[(4,7),(5,8),(6,9)]]
```

What is the fastest way to achieve this? I'm using python 2.

Comment: I think `np.stack([x, y], axis=-1)` (cant check now) will give you a 3D array of the shape that you want. You could then use `.tolist()` if you really need a list.

Comment: Do you need your innermost pair to be a `tuple`or does a `list` work as well?

Answer (score 3):

`stack` is a newish, handy way of creating an array like this.  It's like `np.array` but lets us specify the new axis:

```
In [117]: x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
     ...: y = np.array([[1,2,3],[7,8,9]])
     ...: 
In [118]: x.shape
Out[118]: (2, 3)
In [119]: np.stack((x,y),axis=2)
Out[119]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 7],
        [5, 8],
        [6, 9]]])
```

Without `stack` you can combine the arrays on a new first axis, and then change the order of the axes:

```
In [120]: np.array((x,y))
Out[120]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
In [121]: np.array((x,y)).transpose(1,2,0)
Out[121]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 7],
        [5, 8],
        [6, 9]]])
```

Note that a 3d array like this is not, technically, a 2d array of tuples.  But for most purposes it is better than that.

`stack` (and `dstack`) expand the dimensions to the input arrays, and do a concatenate on that new dimension.  In other words, they do:

```
In [123]: np.concatenate((x[...,None],y[...,None]),axis=-1)
Out[123]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 7],
        [5, 8],
        [6, 9]]])
```